# Static Utility Methods - explicit NULL check vs @NonNull vs explicit throws

Tags: java, exception, lombok

The question is basically for Static Utility Classes, which exist in a package to provide certain functionality to other classes. I'll take a common example stripParenthesis()

`Method 1. Explicit Null Check`

```
public static String stripParenthesis(String str) {
    if(str == null) {
        return str;
    }
    return str.replaceAll("[()]",""); // remove paarenthesis
}
```

`Method 2. Using Lombok's @NonNull`

```
/* @NonNull will throw NPE */
public static String stripParenthesis(@NonNull String str) {

    return str.replaceAll("[()]",""); // remove paarenthesis
}
```

`Method 3. Explicit NPE`

```
public static String stripParenthesis(String str) throws NullPointerException {

    if(str == null) {
        throw NPE();
    }
    return str.replaceAll("[()]",""); // remove paarenthesis
}
```

All the 3 methods are correct. I do not prefer 2nd approach since it throws a NPE as unchecked exception. The caller can unexpectedly fail.

Is there a general convention to follow here?

Comment: According the book Effective Java by Joshua Bloch, I think method 3 should be most advisable in most cases.  However, depending on your specific requirements, you may need to return null when input string is null as in method 1.

Comment: Yeah, that seems they way to go to me also.

Comment: Think about using `Optional`.

Comment: I would argue that the general convention for `String` handling utilities is that they handle `null`s _silently_; if you pass in a `null` value, they return `null`. For inspiration, have a look at the widely-used [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) class from Apache commons.lang. Here's a quote from the docs: "A side effect of the `null` handling is that a `NullPointerException` should be considered a bug in `StringUtils`". As suggested by Tom, returning an `Optional<String>` might be one option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not use method 1 as ignoring `null` usually means it blows somewhere else instead, where the problem may get harder to track. Let no method accept `null`s unnecessarily and you'll see no NPEs as there'll no `null`s anywhere. Use a method like `Strings#nullToEmpty` to get rid of `null` ASAP.

> I do not prefer 2nd approach since it throws a NPE as unchecked exception. The caller can unexpectedly fail.

An NPE is always unchecked. You can use 2' and declare it, but this doesn't make it really better, as a `@NonNull` argument declaration is actually stating what happens in the clearest possible way. It's `@Documented`, which means that it appears in the javadoc.

Comment: Yeah I got that point, when I wrote a unit test for the method. Lombok's @NonNull explicitly throws a NPE with the parameter name that was null. And yes, NPE is unchecked, so the caller has to be careful while calling the utility method.

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1. Explicit Null Check.**

> if(str == null) {
>           return str;
>       }

What do you try to achieve returning null? This masking error by delegating needed null checks and behaviours back to the caller. Maybe you presume returning of something like `Optional.empty()`?

**Method 2. Using Lombok's @NonNull** - isn't an equal option. 
This isn't a part of the java standard with related third party frameworks problems. The javax similar annotations are, but they're not forcing null checks, they designed mostly for static analysers. Despite this, Lombok is reliable framework.

**Method 3. Explicit NPE** - core solid method, it works always, if you hesitate only between that three - use it.